# How does one select an entire worksheet with Spreadsheet gear (.NET)

Tags: spreadsheetgear

I am using the Spreadsheet gear component and need to select all cells in a worksheet so I can apply a consistent font setting across.  How do you create an IRange that represents an entire worksheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IWorksheet.[Cells](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012~SpreadsheetGear.IWorksheet~Cells.html) represents all cells in a worksheet:

workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"].Cells.Font.Color = SpreadsheetGear.Colors.Yellow;

Comment: Right, duh.  Should have realized Cells is an IRange as well.